# React - ES6 template strings with HTML tags embedded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How can I use HTML markup in a ES6 Template String?
The following:

```
{ this.props.rule.conditions.map(e => `<li>${ e.booleanOperator } / ${ e.column }</li>`) }
```

just outputs plain text:

```
<li>Blah / Blah</li><li>Blah / Blah</li><li>Blah / Blah</li>
```

instead of an actual formatted HTML list. It will be used like a loop.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by a "clean list".

Comment: You don't need to use Template Strings at all for this. Simply remove `, and $.

Comment: @zero298 I meant Html formatted list. Sorry for the confusion, I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template string usage is exactly right if you were using normal Javascript and `.innerHTML` to set the text.

However, in React it's converted to a normal string (HTML characters stripped). This is to prevent a [very prevalent form of website hacking, XSS](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+xss).

#### In this case, you can just keep using React elements.

Go ahead and simply remove the "`"s and "$"s completely.

```
<ul>
    { this.props.rule.conditions.map(e => 
        <li>{ e.booleanOperator } / { e.column }</li>
    ) }
</ul>
```

Now it just looks like the same React you're using everywhere else. This is the real sweet part about using React: you can jump in and out of elements and loops and functions just like that! And react will convert it all to actual HTML elements.

Comment: Thank you for the full explanation, It's really useful and I now get what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need not use template strings for this. You can achieve the same thing as:

```
getMarkup = (e)=> {
 return (
  <li>
     {e.boolenaOperator}{e.column}
  </li>
 )
}
{ this.props.rule.conditions.map(e => {this.getMarkup(e)} }
```

Answer (score -2):

Just place your expression in one **${}** placeholder for it to be evaluated .

Example:

```
{ this.props.rule.conditions.map(e => `<li>${ e.booleanOperator / e.column }</li>`) }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: why string literal is required in this?

Comment: assuming this is an arithmetic operation ... literal is used to avoid concat with + operator ...

Comment: simply without **``**: `this.props.rule.conditions.map(e => <li>{e.booleanOperator / e.column }</li>) }`